# Arduino state not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am currently working on a small project using arduino and the below is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; // Four rows
const byte COLS = 3; // Three columns

// Define the Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'#','0','*'}
};

// Connect keypad ROW0, ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 to these Arduino pins.
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
// Connect keypad COL0, COL1 and COL2 to these Arduino pins.
byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8}; 

// Create the Keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

#define ledpin 13
#define LOCKED 2
#define PASSWORD_OK 1
#define UNLOCKED 0

//State Variables; initialise to locked state
int LockState = LOCKED;
int position = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Initialize state and communications
  setLockState(LOCKED);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if(key)  // Check for a valid key.
  {
    switch (key)
    {
//      case '*':
//        digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);
//        break;
//      case '#':
//        digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
//        break;
      default:
        Serial.print(key);
    }
  }
}
```

It was from Adafruit. however, when i upload to my uno, it keeps giving me the error: `'setLockState' was not declared in this scope.`

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not declare the function `setLockState()` in your code. I don't know about your project details, but  it looks like you want to lock a thing via keypad or fingerprint. You can find a great Tutorial (including the missing `setLockState()` function) for a [biometric-security-box](https://learn.adafruit.com/biometric-security-box/program-and-test) on the website of Adafruit.

Comment: Whoops i am so sorry for the dumb question i found out after a while hahaha thanks!